# IE < 9 + HighCharts don't render series

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, highcharts

Hello I have a problem with HighCharts under IE < 9.

[Internet explorer HighCharts screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzeCY.png)

[HighCharts works fine in other browsers screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULxa9.png)

As you can see the chart is rendered in IE and in Chrome but..
The lines are rendered just in the Chrome, the data has to be there also for IE because legend box is there (Best Bid, Qualification Value ...)

The code(By the way it's erb template so I load data from Rails):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  "use strict";
  var chart;
  // assign data for current and qualification values
  var qualificationTranslation = "<%= t(:qualification_value_nobr) %>";
  var currentTranslation = "<%= t(:event_current_value) %>";
  var qualificationValue = <%= @lot.qualification_value %>
  var currentValue = <%= @lot.current_value %>

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var parseChartData = function(data) {
      var chartData = [];
      jQuery.each(data, function(index, value) {
        chartData.push({
          x: Date.parse(value.x),
          y: parseFloat(value.y),
          formated_value: value.formated_value
        });
      });
      return chartData;
    };
    var dataForChart = parseChartData(<%= raw data[:chart_data].to_json %>);

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart',
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'x',
        marginRight: 25
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: "<%= t(:total_difference_progression_chart) %>",
        x: -20 //center
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%I:%M %p', this.value)
          }
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
         text: "<%= t(:bid_value_price_per_uom_x_quantity, :symbol => @lot.event.currency.symbol) %>"
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          var serieName = this.point.series.name;
          // Don't show tooltip when you hover over qualification or current price
          if(serieName == qualificationTranslation || serieName == currentTranslation) {
            return false;
          } else {
            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
            Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %I:%M:%S %p', this.x) +
            '<br/><b>'+ this.point.formated_value + '</b>';
          }
        }
      },
      legend: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 20,
        shadow: true
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          step: true
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: "<%= t(:best_bid) %>",
        data: dataForChart
      }]
    });

    // This function will add the current price and qualification price lines
    var addOrUpdateSerie = function(name, value, serie) {
      var data = []

      data.push([chart.xAxis[0].min, value])
      data.push([chart.xAxis[0].max, value])

      var options = {
        name: name,
        type: 'spline',
        dashStyle: 'shortdot',
        marker: {enabled: false},
        data: data
      }

      if(!serie) {
        chart.addSeries(options);
      } else {
        serie.setData(data)
      }
    };

    addOrUpdateSerie(qualificationTranslation, qualificationValue);
    addOrUpdateSerie(currentTranslation, currentValue);

    socket = io.connect(
      ioServerAddr + '/charts',
      {query: "lot_id=<%= @lot.id %>", secure: isProduction}
    )

    socket.on('connect', function() {
      socket.emit('join', 'host_difference_progression_event_chart');
    });

    socket.on('<%= @lot.id %>/host_difference_progression_event_chart', function(data) {
      // Add data to series
      chart.series[0].setData(parseChartData(data.chart_data))
      //Update hirizontal values
      addOrUpdateSerie(qualificationTranslation, qualificationValue, chart.series[1])
      addOrUpdateSerie(currentTranslation, currentValue, chart.series[2])

      chart.redraw();
    });
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT: It raises NO error**

**SOLVED:**
The problem was with Date.parse() because IE uses other format.
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-httpdate solved the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8790973/1288

Comment: you should add an answer and accept it, so the question does not appear in the "unanswered" list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The problem was with Date.parse() because IE uses other format. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-httpdate solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

I find a solution to render Highcharts on IE7, IE8 and more !

Add this :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=IE7">
```

I don't know why this works but it works :)

Comment: Could you please post those solutions? Right now this answer is empty.